# set back value after for loop is completed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for-loop, vuejs2

I've have following code with a problem.

After clicking my `button` in my template my `counter` will be incremented. Now I want to check if my `counter` is higher, lower or equal to a `length` of an array.

After doing my `for-loops` I want to set my `counter` back to zero.

I've tried with `return this.counter = 0` - but this didn't work.

Thanks in advance for helping me out!

```
methods: {
  if(this.counter > this.lengthArray) { 
    for(let i = this.lengthArray; i <= this.counter; i++) {
      //Do some code
    }
  } else if (this.lengthArray > this.counter) {
    for(let i = 1; i <= this.counter; i++) {
      //Do some code as well
    }
  } else if (counter == 0) {
    //Process another code
  }
},

data() {
  return {
    counter: 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the method to `return` the value `this.counter = 0`.

Setting `this.counter = 0` after your last condition should work. Nothing should return or break the loops.